# How do I convert UTF-8 encoded files to MacOS Roman and vice versa?

Tags: terminal, text, encoding

I'm editing some Japanese cue files, and testing them against [Cog](https://cog.losno.co/) and VLC, but I noticed corrupted-like, obfuscated text inside the cue file. Cog seems to be able to read this text, but VLC shows the exact same text without any conversions...

```
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "§™§·§«§»§¶£°"
    PERFORMER "Various"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

What should actually be in place of `TITLE "..."` should be some japanese text simply saying `おめでとう！`. Simple editing in Text Editor shows that text is encoded as `MACROMAN` when I try to paste in Japanese text & save it. When I try to save the Japanese text as a duplicate of the file in `UTF-8` encoding, I get even further obfuscated text.

The main goal that I want is to be able to convert the `MACROMAN` text to Japanese characters in `UTF-8` or a format that supports it, and to be able to convert `UTF-8` back to `MACROMAN` to get that corrupted (but still readable) text.

I'm sure it is possible. Putting the cue file in VLC shows the exact same text, but Cog does some magic (programming) to convert the `MACROMAN` encoded text to Japanese from the cue file. I've also done sufficient checking to make sure that Cog isn't getting the metadata from somewhere else, like the source audio for chapters.

I have also tried `iconv -f MACROMAN -t UTF8 [file here] > [output stream]` which also yielded same results as if I used Text Editor.

So, can I convert `MACROMAN` to readable Japanese, and convert edits of said Japanese back to `MACROMAN`?

Comment: Where are the cue files coming from, seems that the encoding got messed up already before you got them.